# How to add sub count in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, janitor

I have below-mentioned dataframe in R:

```
dput(df)

structure(list(CustID = c("C-1", "C-2", 
"C-2", "C-2", "C-3", "C-3", 
"C-3", "C-4", "C-5"), DATE = c("2021-01-02 14:13:10", "2021-01-02 13:17:07", "2021-01-02 14:15:10", "2021-01-02 16:14:08", "2021-01-02 17:11:03", "2021-01-02 12:14:24", "2021-01-02 12:33:34", "2021-01-02 10:43:55", "2021-01-03 20:23:35"), TYPE = c("Demo", 
"Pro", "Pro", "Pro", "Pro", "Pro", "Pro", "Pro", "Pro"
), LogCat = c(NA, "SPR,DET,RTD", "SPR,DET,RTD", "SPR,DET,RTD", 
"DET", "DET", "DET", NA, " SPR, RTD "), PriceCode = c(NA,"KR", "SR", "DE", "KL", "ZT", "KR", "KR", "KR")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))

CusID     Date                   Type        LogCat             PriceCode
C-1       2021-01-02 14:13:10    Demo                           
C-2       2021-01-02 13:17:07    Pro         SPR, DET, RTD      KR
C-2       2021-01-02 14:15:10    Pro         SPR, DET, RTD      SR
C-2       2021-01-02 16:14:08    Pro         SPR, DET, RTD      DE
C-3       2021-01-02 17:11:03    Pro         DET                KL
C-3       2021-01-02 12:14:24    Pro         DET                ZT
C-3       2021-01-02 12:33:34    Pro         DET                KR
C-4       2021-01-02 10:43:55    Pro                            KR
C-5       2021-01-03 20:23:35    Pro         SPR, RTD           KR
```

I'm using the following code which give me below-mentioned output.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)
df %>% mutate(DATE = as.Date(DATE)) %>% select(1:3) %>%
  unique() %>%
  tabyl(TYPE, DATE) %>%
  adorn_totals("row") %>%
  adorn_percentages("col") %>%
  adorn_pct_formatting(2) %>%
  adorn_ns("front")

  TYPE  2021-01-02  2021-01-03
  Demo 1  (25.00%) 0   (0.00%)
   Pro 3  (75.00%) 1 (100.00%)
 Total 4 (100.00%) 1 (100.00%)
```

In the above mentioned output, I need the distinct sub count based on column `LogCat` and `PriceCode`. For Example, in the give total distinct count for particular `Type` I need to get the number how many distinct `CusID` has `LogCat` and `PriceCode`. Also, how many distinct count doesn't have `LogCat` and `PriceCode`.

Where, For each type we need to check the following condition.

- `LogCat` - Where an unique `CusID` has only value in `LogCat` colum and `PriceCode` is either NA or Blank
- `PriceCode` - Where an unique `CusID` has only value in `PriceCode` colum and `LogCat` is either NA or Blank
- `Both True` - Where an unique `CusID` has value in both `LogCat` and `PriceCode` column.
- `Both False` - Where an unique `CusID` has no value in both `LogCat` and `PriceCode` column.

The percentage for these values should be calculated by taking the distinct count of a particular `Type` for which we are calculating these values. For Example, below `Demo` if we are calculating these value for `Demo` type then the denominator should be 1 for first date and 0 for the second date.

Required Dataframe<-

```
  TYPE           2021-01-02   2021-01-03
  Demo           1 (25.00%)   0 (0.00%)
  LogCat         0 (0.00%)    0 (0.00%)
  PriceCode      0 (0.00%)    0 (0.00%)
  Both True      0 (0.00%)    0 (0.00%)
  Both False     1 (100.00%)  0 (0.00%) 
  Pro            3 (75.00%)   1 (100.00%)
  LogCat         0 (0.00%)    0 (0.00%)
  PriceCode      1 (33.33%)   0 (0.00%)
  Both True      2 (66.66%)   1 (100.00%)
  Both False     0 (0.00%)    0 (0.00%)
  Total          4 (100.00%)  1 (100.00%)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I understanding from your OP - quite complicated logics ;)

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)

# grain level data-frame
grain_df <- df %>%
  # convert Date to Date
  mutate(DATE = as.Date(DATE)) %>%
  separate_rows(LogCat) %>%
  # Categorize customer into your define logic
  group_by(DATE, TYPE, CustID) %>%
  summarize(category = case_when(
    # all LogCat is missing & Price is present
    all(is.na(LogCat)) & any(!is.na(PriceCode)) ~ "Missing_LogCat",
    # LogCat is present & Price is missing
    any(!is.na(LogCat)) & all(is.na(PriceCode)) ~ "Missing_PriceCode",
    # Both present
    any(!is.na(LogCat)) & any(!is.na(PriceCode)) ~ "Both_True",
    # Both missing
    all(is.na(LogCat)) & all(is.na(PriceCode)) ~ "Both_True",
    TRUE ~ "No category yet"
  ), .groups = "drop") %>%
  # count the customer in each category by type & date
  group_by(DATE, TYPE, category) %>%
  summarize(count = n_distinct(CustID), .groups = "drop") %>%
  # compelete the data set with all combination of Date/type/category
  complete(DATE, TYPE, category, fill = list(count = 0))
```

```r
# summarize and put in some formmating
summary_df <- grain_df %>%
  # calculate the percent
  group_by(DATE, TYPE) %>%
  mutate(percent = paste0(count, " (", percent(count / sum(count)), ")")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-count) %>%
  # Pivot wider to have the format you want
  pivot_wider(names_from = DATE, values_from = percent, values_fill = "")

# calculate total row & formatting
total_rows <- grain_df %>%
  group_by(DATE) %>%
  summarize(percent = paste0(sum(count), " (100%)")) %>%
  mutate(TYPE = "Total", category = "") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = DATE, values_from = percent)
```

```r
# combind two data to get a final df with total rows
bind_rows(summary_df,
  total_rows)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>   TYPE  category         `2021-01-02` `2021-01-03`
#>   <chr> <chr>            <chr>        <chr>       
#> 1 Demo  "Both_True"      1 (100%)     0 (NA)      
#> 2 Demo  "Missing_LogCat" 0 (0%)       0 (NA)      
#> 3 Pro   "Both_True"      2 (67%)      1 (100%)    
#> 4 Pro   "Missing_LogCat" 1 (33%)      0 (0%)      
#> 5 Total ""               4 (100%)     1 (100%)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

And here is a way to generate some pivot style table in RStudio

```
library(kableExtra)
kbl(summary_df, align = "c") %>%
  kable_paper(full_width = F) %>%
  column_spec(1:2, bold = T) %>%
  collapse_rows(columns = 1:2, target = 1, valign = "top")
```

This will output in the `View` tab in `RStudio` this table

[image: Pivot similar]

Comment: It worked fined. Is it possible to keep the `Type` value at above these four variables instead of creating separate column for type with multiple same value?

Comment: Yes, there is, thorugh it not really a good data format and require a lot of extra effort to format the data that way. For presentation I recommend output the data at grain level to excel then pivot them so that you get some beautiful markup or use some packages similar to the one I added into my answers.

Comment: One last thing, How do I add `Total` column at the bottom?

Comment: I updated the answer with a way to calculate total and added them into the bottom of the summary df. I also separate the calculation of grain level data for your reference if you may want to explore more.

Answer (score 1):

package `pivottabler` may help here

```
df %>% mutate(DATE = as.Date(DATE)) %>%
  mutate(across(.cols = c(LogCat, PriceCode), ~ +!(is.na(.) | . == ""))) %>%
  mutate(dummy = case_when(LogCat + PriceCode == 0 ~ "Both False",
                           LogCat + PriceCode == 2 ~ "Both True",
                           LogCat == 1 ~ "Logcat",
                           TRUE ~ "PriceCode")) %>%
  mutate(dummy = factor(dummy, levels = c("Both False", "Both True", "Logcat", "PriceCode")),
         d2 = 1) %>%
  group_by(CustID, DATE, TYPE) %>%
  complete(dummy) %>% ungroup() %>% unique() %>%
  select(c(2:4,7)) -> df1

library(pivottabler)  

qpvt(df1, c("TYPE", "dummy"), "DATE", "sum(d2, na.rm = T)")

                   2021-01-02  2021-01-03  Total  
Demo   Both False           1                  1  
       Both True            0                  0  
       Logcat               0                  0  
       PriceCode            0                  0  
       Total                1                  1  
Pro    Both False           0           0      0  
       Both True            2           1      3  
       Logcat               0           0      0  
       PriceCode            1           0      1  
       Total                3           1      4  
Total                       4           1      5
```

or

```
qhpvt(df1, c("TYPE", "dummy"), "DATE", "sum(d2, na.rm = T)")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks again. can we have the sub status rows irrespective if its true or false?

Comment: Not like this one, the format that you prepared earlier. See my output.

Comment: In 'janitor' one can only have counts. So if we complete na values, that are counted too. If you are ok with exclusion of 0 rows/cols I may give you a syntax